# Generate arrays on runtime

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new in C# and I am trying to find a way to generate arrays at runtime! What i want to do is really simple. I want to press a button and store my results to an array and at the same time the program to create another array for the next entries that i would like to put. I search a lot using my articles title or sth like generate name of array, but nothing came up to help me. I would appreciate if someone can propose a solution or key words in order to search the internet and find sth like this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue but.. why not create a new array, and put it in a list of arrays?

Comment: You should read up on [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a `List<Results>`, something like:

```
List<Results> myResults = new List<Results>();

//...

public void BtnClick(...)
{
    Results results = GetResultsForInput();
    myResults.Add(results);
}

//..
//..

public class Results
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string SomethingElse { get; set; } 
}
```

I'd read up on generic collections, especially List<>

Comment: ...and if you really need an array, you can just call `myList.ToArray()` when you need it. Availability of this method depends on which .NET framework you're using; but I assume you (OP) use the most recent one, unless stated otherwise. I suggest you keep working with Lists if you can. But f there's some reason you specifically need an array, you can always convert arrays to lists and back :)

Answer (score 0):

it is best to do it in lists

```
public List<MyClass> myList= new List<MyClass>();
```

and then

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();     
//do some stuff    
myList.Add(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay on you button click event just create a new array of list. For example if you want to save strings in array you can do following:

```
var names = new List<string>();    
names.Add("test");
```

Comment: The least you could do is use proper capitalization.

Comment: And note that a `List<string>` is not an array. Both arrays and `List<>`s are collections, but they're not the same thing. "Array of list" makes no sense with the code you've given, either...

Comment: i know that....i purposely used it since the question looks primitive!!! and he seems to be new to c#